# Modeling complex libraries/templates in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

For our service activities in our Dynamics CRM we've got a few 100 different atomic activities (only a handful of entities) which are pre-configured for needed amount of time, skills and resources.

Those activities are then grouped into more complex activities where necessary. Both that atomic and the complex activities are our activity library.

Now, when one of our customers opens a support case, we would like to have a referency to our activity library to treat it as template.

What should happen is, that we are copying the referenced activity including the dependent activities.

Is there any built-in support for templates or do we have to code all ourselves?

Comment: Please add a `dynamics-crm-version` tag to your post. In questions about supported features in particular the version you are working with is most relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics CRM (up to 2016) does not support activity templates. So, I guess you need to code it yourself.